# python-binance installation gives an errors

Tags: python, visual-studio, binance

I have been trying to install python-binance for Python 3.9.1 through visual studio code.

When installing with pip install, I get errors in red font!

How could I solve this problem?

the appeared part of error messages :

```
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted
copying src\twisted\copyright.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted
copying src\twisted\plugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted
copying src\twisted\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted
copying src\twisted\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted
copying src\twisted\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\application
copying src\twisted\application\app.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\application
copying src\twisted\application\internet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\application
copying src\twisted\application\reactors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\application
copying src\twisted\application\service.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\application
copying src\twisted\application\strports.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\application
copying src\twisted\application\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\application
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\conch
copying src\twisted\conch\avatar.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\conch
copying src\twisted\conch\checkers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\conch
copying src\twisted\conch\endpoints.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\conch
copying src\twisted\conch\error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\conch
copying src\twisted\conch\interfaces.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\conch
copying src\twisted\conch\ls.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\conch
```

...
...
...
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(5786): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6146): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6164): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6509): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(7614): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
C:\Users\engmn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8421): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8437): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\engmn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\engmn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q9rom09c\twisted_369e0d6970754ea39c620360dd2db963\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\engmn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q9rom09c\twisted_369e0d6970754ea39c620360dd2db963\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\engmn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-33nq2ep1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\engmn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include\Twisted' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: I think the `Twisted` library doesn't support python 3.9, try using with 3.7

Comment: I had issues installing python-binance on python 3.9. Uninstalled and installed python 3.8 and it worked straight away. I think the Twisted package is where it falls over specifically.

Comment: you are right, thanks a lot. 
@Andrew-Stone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Python 3.9, you can download Twisted from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted) and pip install it, then install python-binance

Comment: Yes, that is right, I thought like that but I tried with version 3.8 and it worked well.

thank you @Bugzilla